# How to create a vf page to with controller with a list of accounts

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

Since i am new to salesforce, I would like to create one simple page with custom controller? Can any one give a small class and page that how to call controller in vf page?

Comment: Http://Trailhead.salesforce.com

Comment: I would advise to take a look into this trailhead (https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/module/visualforce_fundamentals). It will give you all the help you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty simple, I agree with the comments to look at [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/) for a much more in depth explanation and experience.

What you'd need is:

- A Visualforce Page that references your custom Controller
- An `<apex:PageBlockTable>` that references the list of accounts you've got
- Columns in the table that references the fields you get

So, to get a list of Accounts via a custom controller could be as simple as:

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" controller="MyCoolController"> // Calling the Apex class called "MyCoolController"
    <apex:pageblock>
        <apex:pageblocktable value="{!accountList}" var="acc"> // Getting all Accounts in accountList, individually know as acc
            <apex:column value="{!acc.Id}" />
            <apex:column value="{!acc.Name}" />
            <apex:column value="{!acc.Custom_Field__c}" /> // Get the fields defined in the query
        </apex:pageblocktable>
    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:page>
```

The class could then look like this:

```
public class MyCoolController {
    public List<Account> accountList { // Create something for your VF page to look at
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MyCoolController() { // When the controller is called, query and populate accountList
        accountList = [Select Id, Name, Custom_Field__c FROM Account LIMIT 10];
    }
}
```

It's that simple in ~20 lines of code. But do look at Trailhead, because it's resources are very useful and will go in to a lot more detail, allowing you to do much cooler things.

Comment: Very nice explanation @Dan Jones.